# is there difference between debug and release reference path while compiling?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am building a SL3 + RIA application in VS2008. When compiled the application in debug mode it compiles fine with out any error, but when I compile the same application with out any code change in release mode I get an error

'The type of namespace name 'BusyIndicator' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference).

All the errors are coming from the generated code *name*.g.cs

Just curious anyone run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This still happens when you do a Clean and/or Rebuild?

I've seen odd issues with the *.g.cs files, try just adjusting something immaterial in the xaml to force the re-creation of the *.g.cs file.